# How do I get the coordinates of the cursor relative to the Image control?

Tags: c#, maui

There is a control Image. How can I get the coordinates of the cursor relative to it and not to the application window?

```
<Image x:Name="Image" MaximumWidthRequest="800" MaximumHeightRequest="800" />
```

This is a MAUI application. As I understand this control has no MouseMove event? What can you do then?

Comment: Maui does not yet have a concept of mouse or cursor. (Due to its Xamarin Forms history, written when mobile device OSes lacked any support for mouse/trackpad.) There is an open proposal [Desktop platforms: Mouse and Keyboard classes or DependencyServices](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/3739). You could create a Windows-specific handler for `Image` element, and use WinUI 3 mouse calls. This is an advanced topic; hopefully someone with specific knowledge will post some code.